# Should I add new method to the interface to use it more commonly or just separate the new logic completely

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance

I have a `CouponReservationService` in an e-commerce project.

It is called when a coupon is reserved to be applied to a basket. It checks that whether the coupons are already reserved. If they are reserved then throws an exception to prevent re-usage. If not then reserves them and allows to be applied.

Currently the reservation logic is only depending on `PaymentType`.

What is asked me to develop is add new reservation logic depending on `couponType`.

Now, I should reserve a coupon if it's in a certain type but this reservation should not prevent the coupon being applied to a basket but prevents only for some other operations on coupon. I also need to keep the current `paymentType` based reservation logic as-is.

The service currently looks like this:

```
    @Autowired 
    private List<CouponReservationStorage> reservationStorages; //We have 3 different implementations here

    public void reserveCoupons(Buyer buyer, List<IssuedVoucher> usedCoupons, PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform) {
        Set<Long> couponIdList = transformUsedCouponsAsIdList(usedCoupons);
        validateCouponsForReservation(buyer, couponIdList);
        CouponReservationStorage storingCache = findStorageBy(paymentPlatform);
        storingCache.store(buyer, couponIdList);
    }

    private CouponReservationStorage findStorageBy(PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform) {
        return reservationStorages.stream().filter(c -> c.canStore(paymentPlatform)).findFirst().get();
    }


    private void validateCouponsForReservation(Buyer buyer, Set<Long> couponsToReserve) {
        for (CouponReservationStorage storage : reservationStorages) {
            if (storage.containsAny(buyer, couponsToReserve)) {
                //throw Exception
            }
        }
    }
```

I have 2 different approaches to add my new functionality here:

**1st** and my preferred method is make reservation logic more generic. Allow the same coupon to be reserved in many storages at the same time.

In this version, I overloaded canStore method in the interface as:

```
default boolean canStore(PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform, IssuedVoucher issuedVoucher) {
        return canStore(paymentPlatform);
    }
```

I override this only in my new type of storage implementation and use the couponType of issuedVoucher to decide to store there or not.

And also added this method to distinguish the new storage implementation should not prevent the coupon being used in the basket:

```
boolean shouldValidateForApplyCoupon();
```

I return true for older ones and false in my new storage implementation.

My **1st** solution looks like below:

```
    @Autowired
    private List<CouponReservationStorage> reservationStorages;

    public void reserveCoupons(Buyer buyer, List<IssuedVoucher> usedCoupons, PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform) {
        Set<Long> couponIdList = transformUsedCouponsAsIdList(usedCoupons);
        validateCouponsForReservation(buyer, couponIdList);
        for (CouponReservationStorage couponReservationStorage : reservationStorages) {
            Set<Long> reservableCouponIds = usedCoupons.stream()
                    .filter(iv -> couponReservationStorage.canStore(paymentPlatform, iv))
                    .map(IssuedVoucher::getId)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            if (!reservableCouponIds.isEmpty()) {
                couponReservationStorage.store(buyer, reservableCouponIds);
            }
        }
    }

private void validateCouponsForReservation(Buyer buyer, Set<Long> couponsToReserve) {
        for (CouponReservationStorage cacheStorage : reservationStorages) {
            if (cacheStorage.containsAny(buyer, couponsToReserve)) {
            if (cacheStorage.shouldValidateForApplyCoupon() && (cacheStorage.containsAny(buyer, couponsToReserve))) {
//                throw Exception
            }
        }
    }
```

My new code allows us to add any new reservation mechanism dynamically. If a next version of reservation mechanism changes depending on Buyer then we just need to add buyer parameter to the canStore method and nothing else changing in old code. And this feels me like plug and play flexibility.

The **2nd** approach, which looks like simpler but not extendible and very feature-specific is:

```
    @Autowired 
    private List<CouponReservationStorage> reservationStorages; //We have 3 different implementations here

    @Autowired 
    private MyNewReservationStorage myNewReservationStorage;

    public void reserveCoupons(Buyer buyer, List<IssuedVoucher> usedCoupons, PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform) {
        Set<Long> couponIdList = transformUsedCouponsAsIdList(usedCoupons);
        validateCouponsForReservation(buyer, couponIdList);
        CouponReservationStorage storingCache = findStorageBy(paymentPlatform);
        storingCache.store(buyer, couponIdList);
        
//To Put in cache
    Set<Long> myCouponIds = usedCoupons.stream()
    .filter(IssuedVoucher::isMyCouponType)
    .map(IssuedVoucher::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    myNewReservationStorage.store(buyer, myCouponIds);
    }

    private CouponReservationStorage findStorageBy(PaymentPlatform paymentPlatform) {
        return reservationStorages.stream().filter(c -> c.canStore(paymentPlatform)).findFirst().get();
    }


    private void validateCouponsForReservation(Buyer buyer, Set<Long> couponsToReserve) {
        for (CouponReservationStorage storage : reservationStorages) {
            if (storage.containsAny(buyer, couponsToReserve)) {
                //throw Exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally for validation and clear-cache flows:
current code and in the 1st approach:

```
public boolean isVoucherReserved(Buyer buyer, Set<Long> issuedVoucherList) {
        return reservationStorages.stream()
                .anyMatch(reservationStorage -> reservationStorage.containsAny(buyer, issuedVoucherList));
    }

    public void cleanReservationFor(Buyer buyer, List<IssuedVoucher> usedCoupons) {
        Set<Long> couponIds = usedCoupons.stream().map(IssuedVoucher::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        reservationStorages.forEach(s -> s.unstore(buyer, couponIds));
    }
```

The 2nd approach it will be changed as:

```
public boolean isVoucherReserved(Buyer buyer, Set<Long> issuedVoucherList) {
        boolean isReservedInPaymentType = reservationStorages.stream()
                .anyMatch(reservationStorage -> reservationStorage.containsAny(buyer, issuedVoucherList));

        if(isReservedInPaymentType){
            return true;
}
        return myNewReservationStorage.containsAny(buyer, issuedVoucherList);

    }


public void cleanReservationFor(Buyer buyer, List<IssuedVoucher> usedCoupons) {
        Set<Long> couponIds = usedCoupons.stream().map(IssuedVoucher::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        reservationStorages.forEach(s -> s.unstore(buyer, couponIds));
        myNewReservationStorage.unstore(buyer, couponIds); //ADDED this line
    }
```

Which approach should I prefer? What are the pros/cons of both approaches?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added my question as the last sentence.